# How to add padding and margin to all Material-UI components?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, customization

I need to add padding or margin to some of Material-UI components, but could not find an easy way to do it. Can I add these properties **to all components**? something like this:

```
<Button color="default" padding={10} margin={5}>
```

I know that this is possible using pure CSS and classes but I want to do it the Material-UI way.

Answer (score 109):

You can use de "Spacing" in a BOX component just by importing the component first:

```
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
```

The Box component works as a "Wrapper" for the component you want to "Modify" the spacing.

then you can use the next properties on the component:

The space utility converts shorthand margin and padding props to margin and padding CSS declarations. The props are named using the format {property}{sides}.

Where property is one of:

m - for classes that set margin
p - for classes that set padding

Where sides is one of:

t - for classes that set margin-top or padding-top

b - for classes that set margin-bottom or padding-bottom

l - for classes that set margin-left or padding-left

r - for classes that set margin-right or padding-right

x - for classes that set both *-left and *-right

y - for classes that set both *-top and *-bottom

blank - for classes that set a margin or padding on all 4 sides of the element

as an example:

```
<Box m={2} pt={3}>
  <Button color="default">
    Your Text
  </Button>
</Box>
```

Comment: For those who are confused by the m={2} pt={3}. These are basically relative to the spacing set in the theme. For example if you have theme like
const theme = {
  spacing: 8,
}
m ={2}sets all margins to 8*2
pt={3} sets padding top to 8*3

Comment: This means using the `Box` component many times. How recommended is this?

Comment: @oskrgg: The docs and various other resources say that `Box` (without any `component` adornment) is shorthand for `div`. It attempts to map each provided prop to a corresponding CSS attribute of its `div`. This is often helpful in keeping such props in the "code" space rather then forcing the developer to find and change styles, themes, and so on. This particular answer strikes me as a recommended and appropriate use. In general, `Box` is no worse than adding a `div`.

Comment: I wonder why the original author (@rostamiani) hasn't accepted this as an answer. If I understand the original question correctly, then this answers it -- it has certainly been helpful for me, and I got here because I think I have the same need as the original question.

Comment: @TomStambaugh maybe the asker want to add a real padding to the `Button`. Adding padding to a `Box` component wrapper is like adding margin to the `Button`.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt actually work :/

Comment: Neither does variants such as `paddingBottom` or `paddingTop`

Comment: @FarhanHaider so what is the default spacing?

Comment: @yaminoyuki 8px is probably the default value https://mui.com/customization/spacing/

Answer (score 35):

> Material-UI's styling solution uses JSS at its core for version 4.x. It's a high performance JS to CSS compiler which works at runtime and server-side.

```
import { withStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const styles = theme => ({
  buttonPadding: {    
    padding: '30px',   
  },
});

function MyButtonComponent(props) {
  const { classes } = props;

  return (      
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        className={classes.buttonPadding}
      >
        My Button
      </Button>
  );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(MyButtonComponent);
```

You can inject styles with withStyle HOC into your component. This is how it works and it's very much optimized.

**EDITED:** To apply styles across all components you need to use `createMuiTheme` and wrap your component with `MuiThemeprovider`

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiButton: {
      root: {
        margin: "10px",
        padding: "10px"
      }
    }
  }
});

 <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
    Custom CSS
  </Button>

  <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
    MuiThemeProvider
  </Button>

  <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
    Bootstrap
  </Button>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Comment: Yes, it works for a specific component. But How can I declare these props for all MUI components?

Comment: you can createMuiTheme for this and wrap your component  in MuiThemeProvider

Comment: I don't want to add padding and margin to all components. I need to add these properties to customize it for each component.

Comment: "Can I add these properties to all components" this your question statement

Comment: Please brief this in your post. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but I said what I'm looking for. Just see the example.

Comment: it's still unclear to me. I don't know if you're trying to use inline styling. You have everything right here

Comment: I need to add some properties to all components just like the example above. Can I have padding and margin properties in all components?

Comment: Of course. You can wrap your main component with muiThemeProvider.

Comment: You are adding padding to all components using muiThemeProvider. But I want to customize paddings for each component. did you look at the example in the question?

Comment: why don't you provide style prop to all your component and do inline styling. But I won't recommend you should declare JSS for each component to utilize the power of JSS in compiling css at runtime and inject in our component.

Comment: Where does the `MuiButton` reference come from? Is this from some MUI API? Why not `Button`?

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is not about injecting styles into components. The author wants to make the padding and margin properties available to all the components. What you are doing is just adding a fixed style to all components.

Answer (score 17):

In Material-UI v5, one can change the button style using the [`sx`](https://next.material-ui.com/system/basics/#the-sx-prop) props. You can see the margin/padding system properties and its equivalent CSS property [here](https://material-ui.com/system/spacing/#api).

```
<Button sx={{ m: 2 }} variant="contained">
  margin
</Button>
<Button sx={{ p: 2 }} variant="contained">
  padding
</Button>
<Button sx={{ pt: 2 }} variant="contained">
  padding top
</Button>
<Button sx={{ px: 2 }} variant="contained">
  padding left, right
</Button>
<Button sx={{ my: 2 }} variant="contained">
  margin top, bottom
</Button>
```

The property shorthands like `m` or `p` are optional if you want to quickly prototype your component, you can use normal CSS properties if you want your code more readable.

The code below is equivalent to the above but use CSS properties:

```js
<Button sx={{ margin: 2 }} variant="contained">
  margin
</Button>
<Button sx={{ padding: 2 }} variant="contained">
  padding
</Button>
<Button sx={{ paddingTop: 2 }} variant="contained">
  padding top
</Button>
<Button sx={{ paddingLeft: 3, paddingRight: 3 }} variant="contained">
  padding left, right
</Button>
<Button sx={{ marginTop: 2, marginBottom: 2 }} variant="contained">
  margin top, bottom
</Button>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 52124938/how-to-add-padding-and-margin-to-all-material-ui-components]

Comment: What is the advantage/disadvantage of doing padding and margin using sx over sysProps of m* and p*?

Answer (score 7):

```
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';

<Box m={1} p={2}>
  <Button color="default">
    Your Text
  </Button>
</Box>
```

Comment: Please do not post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

We can use **makeStyles** of material-ui to achieve this **without using Box component**.

Create a ***customSpacing*** function like below.

**customSpacing.js**

```js
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const spacingMap = {
  t: "Top", //marginTop
  b: "Bottom",//marginBottom
  l: "Left",//marginLeft
  r: "Right",//marginRight
  a: "", //margin (all around)
};

const Margin = (d, x) => {
  const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
    margin: () => {
      // margin in x-axis(left/right both)
      if (d === "x") {
        return {
          marginLeft: `${x}px`,
          marginRight: `${x}px`
        };
      }
      // margin in y-axis(top/bottom both)
      if (d === "y") {
        return {
          marginTop: `${x}px`,
          marginBottom: `${x}px`
        };
      }
      return { [`margin${spacingMap[d]}`]: `${x}px` };
    }
  }));
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { margin } = classes;
  return margin;
};

const Padding = (d, x) => {
  const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
    padding: () => {
      if (d === "x") {
        return {
          paddingLeft: `${x}px`,
          paddingRight: `${x}px`
        };
      }
      if (d === "y") {
        return {
          paddingTop: `${x}px`,
          paddingBottom: `${x}px`
        };
      }
      return { [`padding${spacingMap[d]}`]: `${x}px` };
    }
  }));
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { padding } = classes;
  return padding;
};

const customSpacing = () => {
  return {
    m: Margin,
    p: Padding
  };
};

export default customSpacing;
```

Now import above **customSpacing** function into your Component and use it like below.
**App.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import customSpacing from "./customSpacing";

const App = () => {
  const { m, p } = customSpacing();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2
        style={{ background: "red" }}
        className={`${m("x", 20)} ${p("x", 2)}`}
      >
        Start editing to see some magic happen!
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[click to open codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-curie-pe9dw?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

We can use makeStyles or styles props on the Typography component to give margin until version 4.0.

I highly recommend to use version 5.0 of material ui and on this version Typography is having margin props and it makes life easy.

Answer (score 0):

## Specific for "padding-top" (10px) using Global style

[Read this!](https://mui.com/customization/theme-components/)

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, makeStyles, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Home } from "@material-ui/icons";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({

container: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(10),
},
}));

const LeftBar = () => {
const classes = useStyles();

return (
    <Container className={classes.container}>
        <div className={classes.item}>
            <Home className={classes.icon} />
            <Typography className={classes.text}>Homepage</Typography>
        </div>
    </Container>
);
};

export default LeftBar;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button color="default" p=10px m='5px'>
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32684798)

Answer (score -2):

set initial spacing first in the themeprovider i.e the tag enclosing you app entry. It should look like this

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import purple from '@material-ui/core/colors/purple';
import green from '@material-ui/core/colors/green';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: purple[500],
    },
    secondary: {
      main: green[500],
    },
  },
});
function App() {
  return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <LandingPage />
      </ThemeProvider>
  );
 }
```

that's it. so add the theme section to the code and use margin/padding as you wish

```
const theme = {
  spacing: 8,
}

<Box m={-2} /> // margin: -16px;
<Box m={0} /> // margin: 0px;
<Box m={0.5} /> // margin: 4px;
<Box m={2} /> // margin: 16px;
```

you can use "margin" or "m" for short same applies to padding
or

```
const theme = {
  spacing: value => value ** 2,
}

<Box m={0} /> // margin: 0px;
<Box m={2} /> // margin: 4px;
```

or

```
<Box m="2rem" /> // margin: 2rem;
<Box mx="auto" /> // margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto
```

Comment: How to allow margin for <Grid/>

Comment: This does not answer the question asked. Box component by default has the padding and margin properties. The questions ask how to add these properties to other components (eg. Button)